# Hyperlinks in VS2008 Test Result Details

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

In case when resulting string in "Test Result Details" (TRD) is very long, the Visual Studio 2008 crashes. I fixed this by sending the result data into a file. There is a problem, however, because there isn't a simple way to open such file. Of course, I can manually open folder and then the file, but it isn't very efficient. Now, to the questions part.

1. Is there a possibility to include in the "Error Message" part of TRD a hyperlink to a file? (something similar to what we can already find in the stack trace part)
2. If not, is there any way to add such functionality (easy opening of a file) to TRD?
3. If not, are there any ways to expand the default reporting of VS?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        ...
        testContextInstance.AddResultFile(targetFile);
    }

    private TestContext testContextInstance;

    /// <summary>
    ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
    ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
    ///</summary>
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't do what I wanted. As far as I've tested, it just copies the given file to the "In" directory. It doesn't display a hyperlink to the file.